# C# generic Type

Tags: c#, java, generics

In java, I can say

```
public void foo(Class<? extends Bar>){}
```

But in C#, is there an equivalent?

```
public void foo(Type<? : Bar>){} //Doesn't work.
public void foo(Type<?> where ? : Bar) //Still doesn't work.
public void foo(Type<T> where T : Bar) //STILL doesn't work!
```

Comment: Yeah you really should've done some homework before asking that question here, no offense.

Comment: You can see the syntax pretty quickly in [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which is also my first Google hit for your exact title.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. i mean Type as in System.Type. The argument to foo is a System.Type, and i want to restrict it like i can a java.lang.Class.

Comment: OH! Wait I see. I should make the method generic instead of the argument. Nevermind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add a generic type constraint to a method, use this syntax:

```
public void foo<T>() where T : Bar 
{
   ...
}
```

Or to add a constraint to a class (or struct / interface), use this:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Bar 
{
   ...
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [where (generic type constraint) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)